# How to separate strings of a column and store them in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to data (see example below). I would like to create a vector containing all the string characters of IIIF separated by a comma as in out.

```
data=data.frame(IIIT=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), IIIF=c("aze,hyt,fre", NA, "ade", "ijh, deg","oij,erf", "eft,kij", "efg,kijj,lerod,kjhyg"))

data
  IIIT                 IIIF
1    a          aze,hyt,fre
2    b                 <NA>
3    c                  ade
4    d             ijh, deg
5    e              oij,erf
6    f              eft,kij
7    g efg,kijj,lerod,kjhyg

out
 [1] "aze"   "hyt"   "fre"   NA      "ade"   "ijh"   "deg"   "oij"   "erf"   "eft"   "kij"   "efg"   "kijj"  "lerod" "kjhyg"
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base R has `strsplit()` which will create a list, with each element of the list being a character vector of each separate word found in the original vector. You can then combine the results using `unlist()`:

```
> unlist(strsplit(data$IIIF, split = ","))
 [1] "aze"   "hyt"   "fre"   NA      "ade"   "ijh"   " deg"  "oij"   "erf"  
[10] "eft"   "kij"   "efg"   "kijj"  "lerod" "kjhyg"
```

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data=data.frame(IIIT=c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"), IIIF=c("aze,hyt,fre", NA, "ade", "ijh, deg","oij,erf", "eft,kij", "efg,kijj,lerod,kjhyg"))

data %>% 
  separate_rows(IIIF, sep=",") %>% 
  select(IIIF) %>% unlist %>% set_names(NULL)

#>  [1] "aze"   "hyt"   "fre"   NA      "ade"   "ijh"   " deg"  "oij"   "erf"  
#> [10] "eft"   "kij"   "efg"   "kijj"  "lerod" "kjhyg"
```

**EDIT**

The solution above can be simplifed, according to @Adam's bellow comment, which I thank:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  separate_rows(IIIF, sep=",") %>% 
  pull(IIIF)
```

Comment: It would be far more effective to simply use `pull()` instead of `select()` and end the pipe there. No need for the `unlist()` and `set_names()`.

Comment: Thanks, @Adam, to let me know that! I have just edited my solution, to incorporate your comment.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `scan` like below

```
> scan(text = data$IIIF, sep = ",", what = "character")
Read 15 items
 [1] "aze"   "hyt"   "fre"   NA      "ade"   "ijh"   " deg"  "oij"   "erf"
[10] "eft"   "kij"   "efg"   "kijj"  "lerod" "kjhyg"
```